# How does data structure affect Excel document?

Tags: excel, memory, processing-efficiency

I currently have an (inherited) document that grows with 25-30 rows every week. I want to change this and have a few options. The number of variables I will have each week for each class is x and I have 3 classes. I have identified the following options:

1. Have it grow with one row each week and have 3x columns.
2. Have it grow with 3 rows each week and have x columns.
3. Have 3 sheets, each which grows with one row every week and has x columns.

Which one is preferable for efficiency and memory purposes?

Comment: Rule 1: more data takes more space. Rule 2: efficiency and memory use are controlled by the functions you use. Test and work out what you need.